# Exercise 1.12 (c) of Silverman "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

I am self-studying "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", but I am having difficulties with Exercise 1.12(c). The problem is as follows:

[image]

---

Some definitions:

[image]

---

The "only if" part is easy. For the "if" part, I have made some attempts:

> $\phi^\sigma=\phi$ implies that, for each $\sigma\in G_{\bar K/K}$ and
> $P\in V_1$,
>
> $$[f_0^\sigma(P),\cdots,f_n^\sigma(P)]=[f_0(P),\cdots,f_n(P)].$$
>
> Thus for a fixed $P$, and by (b), $[f_0(P),\cdots,f_n(P)]\in\mathbb P^n(K)$.

Then I got stuck here, and I couldn't figure out how to use (a). Any discussion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $K$ assumed to be perfect? Under what condition are rational maps equal, according to this definition? Is $K(V_1)$ (for a projective variety) the field of rational *functions* on $V_1$, or does it include “homogeneous functions”? Do you know that $K(V_1) \otimes_K L=L(V_1)$ for any extension $K \subset L \subset \overline{K}$?

Comment: 1. $K$ is a perfect field.
2. Yes.
3. $\bar K(V_1)=\bar K[X_1,\cdots,X_n]/I(V_1)$, similar for $K(V_1)$.
4. I don't know.

Comment: You haven’t answered for 2 (if you want a yes-no question, I guess it would be: “are two rational maps equal by definition when they are equal at every point of $V_1$?”). For 3, did you mean $\overline{K}[X_0,\ldots,X_n]$?

Comment: For 2, two rational maps equal when they are equal at every point of $V_1$.
For 3, I mean $X_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\phi=[f_0,\ldots,f_n]$. Then, for every $\sigma \in G_K$, since $\phi^{\sigma}=\phi$, $f_i^{\sigma}/f_i=c_{\sigma}$ for some $c_{\sigma} \in Frac(\overline{K}(V_1))^{\times}$.

So, since $\phi$ is defined over some finite Galois extension $L/K$, we can in fact see $\sigma \longmapsto c_{\sigma}$ as an element of $H^1(Gal(L/K),Frac(L(V_1))^{\times})$.

So we can use Hilbert 90 if we can prove that $Frac(L(V_1))/Frac(K(V_1))$ is Galois of Galois group $Gal(L/K)$.

It’s enough to see that $Frac(L(V_1))^{Gal(L/K)}=K(V_1)$ (because no element of $Gal(L/K)$ acts trivially on $L(V_1)$).

The $\supset$ inclusion is trivial; so let $x=a/b \in Frac(L(V_1))^{Gal(L/K)}$. Let $B=\prod_{s \in Gal(L/K)}{b^s}$: then $B \in L(V_1)^{Gal(L/K)}=K(V_1)$ (by (a)), hence $a=xB \in L(V_1)^{Gal(L/K)}=K(V_1)$ (still by (a)), so $x \in Frac(K(V_1))$, which concludes.